# Swift: Set a NSString property in Objective C class

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

I am fairly new to iOS development, I am trying to figure out how to set the following property defined in .h file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

In my swift class I am trying to set this property as part of segue,

```
  if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController {
    let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
    destination.name = self.names[indexPath.row]
    print(destination.name) //This is Nil
  }
```

but after this `destination.name` is still `Nil`. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct in swift. Now, only thing i can think of that might be keeping your name property nil, would be that your destinationViewController is not kind of class ViewController i.e. i suspect your if statement is not executing. Verify by putting a print statement in your if code, where you are unwrapping destinationViewController.

Comment: Yes, I tried that already and verified that statement is getting executed. And also self.names is valid and it is indexing the right element.

Comment: Where you are trying to access destination.name? Can you please mention some code of that part here. You are setting its property right, now the issue should be in the part, where you are trying to access it.